# grep with --include and --exclude

Tags: grep

I want to search for a string `foo` within the `app` directory, but excluding any file which contains `migrations` in the file name. I expected this `grep` command to work

```
grep -Ir --include "*.py" --exclude "*migrations*" foo app/
```

The above command seems to ignore the `--exclude` filter. As an alternative, I can do

```
grep -Ir --include "*.py" foo app/ | grep -v migrations
```

This works, but this loses highlighting of `foo` in the results. I can also bring `find` into the mix and keep my highlighting.

```
find app/ -name "*.py" -print0 | xargs -0 grep --exclude "*migrations*" foo
```

I'm just wondering if I'm missing something about the combination of command line parameters to grep or if they simply don't work together.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a term on a .py file, but didn't want migration files to be scanned, so what I found (for grep 2.10) was the following (I hope this helps):

```
grep -nR --include="*.py" --exclude-dir=migrations whatever_you_are_looking_for .
```

Answer (score 0):

`man grep` says:

```
       --include=GLOB
          Search only files whose base name  matches  GLOB  (using  wildcard  matching  as  described  under
          --exclude).
```

because it says "only" there, i'm guessing that your `--include` statment is overriding your `--exclude` statement.

Comment: That's what I assumed as well as stated in my question. I'm just curious if there's a way to use those two options together.